# tensorflow runs significantly longer(slower) with intel AVX comparing with non-avx installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, intel, avx

while I was running my training with default installed tensorflow by
`pip install tensorflow`

I run my model with optimizer like

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My fitting runs about 5 seconds for each epoch

```
67/67 - 6s - loss: 0.0023 - accuracy: 0.9995 - 6s/epoch - 90ms/step
```

So I tried intel wheel, in order to run on AVX, or AVX2, as I am running on a I5 processor with them supported, I don't have GPU installed, I suppose it shall be faster than CPU?

```
pip install intel-tensorflow
```

But I get much worse performance, at lease 3 times slower than before:

```
75/75 - 17s - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5590 - 17s/epoch - 226ms/step
Epoch 7/600
75/75 - 25s - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5573 - 25s/epoch - 334ms/step
Epoch 8/600
```

Summary of my enviroment:

```
ubuntu 21.10
python 3.9.7
tensorflow - 2.8.0
```

besides, libmkl-avx2, libmkl-locale is also installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libmkl-avx2
version 2020.4.304-2
```

do I miss anything? Now I removed intel-tensorflow and reinstalled normal distribution, I can run previous performance:

```
75/75 - 4s - loss: 0.3873 - accuracy: 0.8204 - 4s/epoch - 57ms/step
Epoch 57/600
75/75 - 4s - loss: 0.3935 - accuracy: 0.8191 - 4s/epoch - 58ms/step
Epoch 58/600
```

Comment: Was your original build using a GPU for any of the work?  Is intel-tensorflow maybe using pure CPU?

Comment: @PeterCordes Good question, no, I dont have GPU installed

Comment: I don't know Tensorflow that well, but is it significant that the "loss" and "accuracy" numbers are *very* different for the slower times using the Intel version?  Can you reproduce these times doing the same work on the same data but still running slower?

Comment: Also, IDK what you mean by "faster than CPU".  AVX is part of your CPU, and is primarily relevant when using CPU rather than GPU.  If the original version wasn't using AVX and FMA instructions, it would likely have still been using SSE instructions.

Comment: please ignore the 'loss' 'accuracy' I just randomly pick 2 lines of them from thousands, I know AVX is part of CPU, I have been writing some code runs on AVX couple year ago, it provids 128, 256 bits computing capabilities, should be much faster than normal